# Mel scale conversion in pgfmath, decimal point problem

Tags: pgfmath

I am trying to use `pgfmath` to convert frequencies in hertz to the [mel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel_scale) scale. I'm trying to implement a formula for which I have a Java source and which I have previously implemented with success in XSLT. My attempt with `pgfmath` yields the results which I would expect up to 1000, afterwards the decimal place is three places to the right of what I would expect. A small latex file demonstrating the problem follows. It includes Java and XSLT versions of the formula. I am new to `pgfmath` (but regularly use `pgf`) and my numerical math skills have languished for many years, so I am rather clueless at this point.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{pgffor}
% java code borrowed from sphinx4 MelFrequencyFilterBank.java: 
% (2595.0 * (Math.log(1.0 + inputFreq / 700.0) / Math.log(10.0)))
% Implemented in XSLT as follows:
% <xsl:function name="local:hz2mel">
%     <xsl:param name="inputFreq" as="xs:double"/>
%     <xsl:value-of select="2595.0 * (math:log(1.0 + $inputFreq div 700.0)) div math:log(10.0)"/>
% </xsl:function>
% Attempt to implement in pgfmath
\newcommand{\hztomel}[1]{%
  \pgfmathparse{2595.0*ln(1+#1/700)/ln(10)}%
  \pgfmathresult%
}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\foreach \x in {0, 200, 400, 1000, 1001, 2000, 5000,10000}
         {\x{} $\rightarrow$ \hztomel{\x}\\}
\end{document}
```

---

Comment: I get 10000 → 3073.0856 and the site you have linked confirms up to some decimals, is that wrong? Also `log10` function is defined.

Comment: No, it's not wrong. Strangely, when I run the test file through pdflatex I get 10000 → 3.07307 as output in the PDF file. - George

Comment: Maybe your PGF version is outdated. I'm using v2.10. You can check yours by putting `\listfiles` command somewhere in the preamble and reading the log output.

Comment: That must be it then. I have version 1.414213 29/9/2007 from the texlive in debian squeeze. I'll get a newer version and report back. Thanks, George

Comment: Problem solved. I had PGF version v2.00. Using v2.10 I get the correct output. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Great! If you don't mind we'll close the question as `Too localized` since it's an update issue but not a TeX issue.

Comment: It's fine with me to close it. Problem and solution are as clear as they could be.